# CSS to get the overflow div container max width depending on inside elements

Tags: css, html, width, overflow

I have a **container** and **overflow** `<div>` that shows many `<ul> <li>` lists... each  always has the **same number** of items `<li>` inside, both **always bordered**, like a table.

BUT... I can have a case where the `<ul>` has **only one bordered** `<li>`.

When I set the width of the `<li>` to 100%, the Chrome shows the **right border** seted to the margin/limit of the container div width, as shown in the image bellow:

[image]

I´d like the `right border` of the lonely `<li>` should be positioned to the **width limit (overflow)** of the other `<ul> <li>` lists, as shown.

Is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5hr7p/

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Fiddle?

Comment: You've explained the question well, but could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net here so that we could try it?

Comment: Sure!! Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/5hr7p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have look at this:

I changed your viewing container properties to:
(it would work without float:left)

```
div.painel-linear {
width: 100%;    
float: left;    
overflow: hidden;   
overflow-x: scroll; 
 }
```

also added this to your blue border "li" element,
now border and padding are added to overall size of an element, so when you set width to 100% bolder wont stick outside the container :)

```
.obs{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
 }
```

I added /* added */ comments everywhere I added something to your css, 
and haven't added any fixed with or height.

Now  tag

In this version I put it on the top of the box so it doesn't scroll with the content:

http://jsfiddle.net/5hr7p/1/

In this one I left it inside the content but added:

```
h3{
     position:fixed;
}
.painel-linear div.pl-passos {
     margin-top:60px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hr7p/2/

## EDIT

Ok then, to div which you just created add

```
float:left
```

and that's it,

your "ul" with border was expanding only to size of his parent which was "div.painel-linear div.pl-passos" so it couldn't be the same witdh as the rest of ul elements. New div is parent for all ul elements with same width so its possible to expand "ul" with borders to size of the rest of ul.
Hope it makes sense :P

Comment: Amaro, I understood your modifications, It really run ok on jsfiddle, but when I implemented it on production, It doesnt run properly. So I put it online, and if you dont mind, could you inspect it for me? The problem is still appearing. If you see the CSS, I signed lines with /* ADDED BY AMARO */. See: http://www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=linear

Comment: In time... Im using Bootstrap, so some width and height tunning may be overriden by the Bootstrap libs (priority). :(

Comment: Ok let me try... can you do one thing for me, in <div id="pl-scroll" class="col-xs-8 pl-passos"> can you wrap all <ul> elements, just temporary in one div(no styles), because I cannot edit html. Just want to try something.

Comment: Done man, I also reduced the number of elements because there was a lot of trash data... no its more clear. http://www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=linear